# passing attribute of element to a function in angular 4/5

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I want to pass attribute values of elements to a function at a button click and here's how i am doing it

```html
<div>
  <ul #list>
    <li class="radio" *ngFor="let option of options; let j = index" id={{i}}-{{j}} #item>
      <label><input type="radio" #opt  name={{i}} value={{option}} /> {{option}} </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button type="button" (click)='func(opt.value, item.id, list)'>submit</button>
```

what i am doing here is

1. I am passing the value of radio button(first arg)
2. passing the id of the list item(second arg)
3. passing the reference of the entire list (third arg)

But of course it's not working the error message says cannot read value of undefined(first arg) and I suspect the same will happen for the rest of the argument as well.

So my question is how do i pass the attribute value to the function?

PS: I am new to angular stuff

Comment: The template reference variable `opt` is visible only in the `ngFor` loop. We can understand why: since you can have several items in `options`, and consequently several radio input elements, it is not clear which one `opt` would refer to in the button click event handler. The same problem applies to the variable `item`, but the variable `list` should work because it is in the same scope as the button.

Comment: http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/thomas/2017/05/use-angular-template-reference-variables-anywhere-in-the-template-not.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set variables to the selected option's value and item ID on `change()` and pass those in when you click the button.

```
<div>
  <ul #list>
    <li class="radio" *ngFor="let option of options; let j = index" id={{i}}-{{j}} #item>
      <label><input type="radio" #opt name={{i}} value={{option}} (change)="selectedOptionValue=option.value; selectedItemID=item.id" /> {{option}} </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button type="button" (click)='func(selectedOptionValue, selectedItemID, list)'>submit</button>
```

Just be sure to check those values in your backend `func` function to see if they're set.

Comment: Yup did something similiar